# Utilizing achartengine's zoom in non-graph views

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a view that I have overridden the onDraw method to output the info I need onto the canvas.  On the same screen I have a graph so I think it would be most user-friendly if they both used the same zoom/pan mechanism.  Is it possible to override GraphicalView and use the zoom built into achartengine on non-graph views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.
Probably the cleanest way to do this is to register listeners for the pan and zoom operations and when notified about such events, you do your own zoom and pan logic in your view.
Provided that you have an mChartView variable that is an AChartEngine chart view, you can do something like:

```
mChartView.addZoomListener(...);
mChartView.addPanListener(...);
```

Dan